# Is it possible to grey out a div using the bootstrap css?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div that I want to be greyed out. It contains a chart, so when the user presses "Update" I want it to be greyed out while it fetches the data using ajax. Once the response is received and the chart updates, it would be un-greyed out.

Is this possible with the bootstrap framework?

Comment: Sure is possible, with jquery. What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried overlaying the spinner icon `<i id="chart-loading" class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i>` but I'm not sure how to make the background go grey in the process.

Comment: Did you try `default` in css?

Comment: You can use a BS modal for it. [Check this link](http://dotnetspeak.com/2013/05/creating-simple-please-wait-dialog-with-twitter-bootstrap/comment-page-1)

Answer (score 2):

Its possible with [jQuery loadmask](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-loadmask/)

Here is a snippet-

```
  $(document).bind("ajaxSend", function () {
                $('#section').mask("Processing request, Please wait...");
            }).bind("ajaxComplete", function () {
                $('#section').unmask();
            });
```